# Publishing Clean Arhitecture Project with Angular and .net core in Visual Studio

Tags: angular, visual-studio, azure-web-app-service, publish, clean-architecture

I was trying to publish a solution using Visual Studio but I'm really stucked at this point.
I got my little project using [Clean arhitecture solution template](https://github.com/jasontaylordev/CleanArchitecture) but when trying to publish it nothing seems to work.

What I've tried:

- publishing each project one by one, but the frontend (angular) won't communicate with the backend(.net core)
- updating node and python
- reinstalling python and node
- running the visual studio by administrator
- trying to publish the template from github, without my very own code in it
- update the csproj file from
  `npm run build -- --prod`
  to
  `npm run build --prod`

I also tried to look for this error on the internet, I already tried every solution but nothing seems to work for me.

You can find here a picture of the console:
[Link to the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uDilN.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is caused by the local computer environment. I solved it locally, but I don't have a clear solution for you. I can only provide you with ideas, because every environmental computer in our development is different.

**Installed on my pc**

*1. python 3.8*

*2. npm*

*3. node 14*

The best way to solve this problem is to perform a Google search according to the error prompt, so that the problem can be solved step by step. (It took me 2 hours to successfully release the program, but there are still problems with the program after the release, which may be caused by some specific factors)

[image]

**According to your error message,**

1. First install python2.7,
2. Upgrade npm to the latest version,
3. Execute `npm install -g node-sass`.

*Follow the error prompt and perform a Google search for subsequent errors.*

## **Local test results:**

[image]